# How to read environment property into xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, environment-variables

I have environment property in application, like portal.db.pwd.
Now I want to read it into xml, like:

```
<bean id="testBean" class="com.example.service.TestBean" depends-on="customerService" lazy-init="true">
    <!--        <property name="message" value="# {systemProperties['portal.db.password']}" /> -->
        <property name="message" value="${portal.db.password}" />
</bean>
```

try two ways, both of them could not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add properties place holder configuration to use those properties into your XML file,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>yourFile.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```